# Python - How to always generate valid Luhn numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, generate, luhn

**I'm trying to generate valid Luhn numbers using random library** (without using other libraries like fast_luhn)
 I generated a random number, then the last digit is iterated from 0 to 9, each iteration being a new case to check in the function `valid_luhn`, and then the same with the next digit of the first number generated, but I got stuck with this exponential, random and branched idea.

This is my code to validate the numbers using Luhn algorithm (if you have any suggetion to improve it, like use a better list comprehension, let me know):

```
def valid_luhn(cc):
    num = list(map(int, str(cc)))
    return sum(num[::-2] + [sum(divmod(d * 2, 10)) for d in num[-2::-2]]) % 10 == 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution:**

```
from random import randint

def generate_card(type):
    """
    Prefill some values based on the card type
    """
    card_types = ["americanexpress","visa13", "visa16","mastercard","discover"]

    def prefill(t):
        # typical number of digits in credit card
        def_length = 16

        """
        Prefill with initial numbers and return it including the total number of digits
        remaining to fill
        """
        if t == card_types[0]:
            # american express starts with 3 and is 15 digits long
            # override the def lengths
            return [3, randint(4,7)], 13

        elif t == card_types[1] or t == card_types[2]:
            # visa starts with 4
            if t.endswith("16"):
                return [4], def_length - 1
            else:
                return [4], 12

        elif t == card_types[3]:
            # master card start with 5 and is 16 digits long
            return [5, randint(1,5)], def_length - 2

        elif t == card_types[4]:
            # discover card starts with 6011 and is 16 digits long
            return [6, 0, 1, 1], def_length - 4

        else:
            # this section probably not even needed here
            return [], def_length

    def finalize(nums):
        """
        Make the current generated list pass the Luhn check by checking and adding
        the last digit appropriately bia calculating the check sum
        """
        check_sum = 0

        #is_even = True if (len(nums) + 1 % 2) == 0 else False

        """
        Reason for this check offset is to figure out whether the final list is going
        to be even or odd which will affect calculating the check_sum.
        This is mainly also to avoid reversing the list back and forth which is specified
        on the Luhn algorithm.
        """
        check_offset = (len(nums) + 1) % 2

        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            if (i + check_offset) % 2 == 0:
                n_ = n*2
                check_sum += n_ -9 if n_ > 9 else n_
            else:
                check_sum += n
        return nums + [10 - (check_sum % 10) ]

    # main body
    t = type.lower()
    if t not in card_types:
        print("Unknown type: '%s'" % type)
        print("Please pick one of these supported types: %s" % card_types)
        return

    initial, rem = prefill(t)
    so_far = initial + [randint(1,9) for x in range(rem - 1)]
    print ("Card type: %s, " % t,)
    print ("".join(map(str,finalize(so_far))))



# run - check
generate_card("discover")
generate_card("mastercard")
generate_card("americanexpress")

generate_card("visa13")
generate_card("visa16")
```

**Second solution:**

```
from random import Random
import copy

visaPrefixList = [
        ['4', '5', '3', '9'],
        ['4', '5', '5', '6'],
        ['4', '9', '1', '6'],
        ['4', '5', '3', '2'],
        ['4', '9', '2', '9'],
        ['4', '0', '2', '4', '0', '0', '7', '1'],
        ['4', '4', '8', '6'],
        ['4', '7', '1', '6'],
        ['4']]

mastercardPrefixList = [
        ['5', '1'], ['5', '2'], ['5', '3'], ['5', '4'], ['5', '5']]

amexPrefixList = [['3', '4'], ['3', '7']]

discoverPrefixList = [['6', '0', '1', '1']]

dinersPrefixList = [
        ['3', '0', '0'],
        ['3', '0', '1'],
        ['3', '0', '2'],
        ['3', '0', '3'],
        ['3', '6'],
        ['3', '8']]

enRoutePrefixList = [['2', '0', '1', '4'], ['2', '1', '4', '9']]

jcbPrefixList = [['3', '5']]

voyagerPrefixList = [['8', '6', '9', '9']]

def completed_number(prefix, length):
    """'prefix' is the start of the CC number as a string, any number of digits. 
    'length' is the length of the CC number to generate. Typically 13 or 16"""
    ccnumber = prefix

    # generate digits

    while len(ccnumber) < (length - 1):
        digit = str(generator.choice(range(0, 10)))
        ccnumber.append(digit)

    # Calculate sum

    sum = 0
    pos = 0

    reversedCCnumber = []
    reversedCCnumber.extend(ccnumber)
    reversedCCnumber.reverse()

    while pos < length - 1:
        odd = int(reversedCCnumber[pos]) * 2

        if odd > 9:
            odd -= 9
        sum += odd

        if pos != (length - 2):
            sum += int(reversedCCnumber[pos + 1])
        pos += 2

    # Calculate check digit
    checkdigit = ((sum / 10 + 1) * 10 - sum) % 10
    ccnumber.append(str(checkdigit))

    return ''.join(ccnumber)


def credit_card_number(rnd, prefixList, length, howMany):
    result = []

    while len(result) < howMany:
        ccnumber = copy.copy(rnd.choice(prefixList))
        result.append(completed_number(ccnumber, length))

    return result


def output(title, numbers):
    result = []
    result.append(title)
    result.append('-' * len(title))
    result.append('\n'.join(numbers))
    result.append('')

    return '\n'.join(result)

#
# Main
#

generator = Random()
generator.seed()        # Seed from current time

mastercard = credit_card_number(generator, mastercardPrefixList, 16, 10)
print(output("Mastercard", mastercard))

visa16 = credit_card_number(generator, visaPrefixList, 16, 10)
print(output("VISA 16 digit", visa16))

visa13 = credit_card_number(generator, visaPrefixList, 13, 5)
print(output("VISA 13 digit", visa13))

amex = credit_card_number(generator, amexPrefixList, 15, 5)
print(output("American Express", amex))

# Minor cards

discover = credit_card_number(generator, discoverPrefixList, 16, 3)
print(output("Discover", discover))

diners = credit_card_number(generator, dinersPrefixList, 14, 3)
print(output("Diners Club / Carte Blanche", diners))

enRoute = credit_card_number(generator, enRoutePrefixList, 15, 3)
print(output("enRoute", enRoute))

jcb = credit_card_number(generator, jcbPrefixList, 16, 3)
print(output("JCB", jcb))

voyager = credit_card_number(generator, voyagerPrefixList, 15, 3)
print(output("Voyager", voyager))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my credit card number generator. It will ask you for the first 15 digits of a real card so that the generated number will be "issued" by the same financial institution:

```
from random import randint

cc_number = []
multiplied_by_two = []
remaining_numbers = []
new_number = ''

# Ask for a first 15 digits of a card
starting_15 = input('Enter first 15 digits: ')

z = 0
y = 0

while z < 25:
    for i in str(starting_15):
        cc_number.append(int(i))

    # extract all the numbers that have to be multiplied by 2
    for i in cc_number[0:16:2]:
        i *= 2
        if len(str(i)) == 2:        # check if the multiplied number is a two digit number
            for x in str(i):        # if it is, separate them, and add them together
                y += int(str(x))
            i = y
        multiplied_by_two.append(i)
        y = 0

    for i in cc_number[1:15:2]:     # extract remaining numbers
        remaining_numbers.append(i)

    # Luhn's algorithm
    last_digit = ((sum(multiplied_by_two) + sum(remaining_numbers)) * 9) % 10

    for i in cc_number:
        new_number += str(i)

    print(new_number + str(last_digit))
    cc_number = []
    multiplied_by_two = []
    remaining_numbers = []
    new_number = ''

    starting_15 = int(starting_15) + randint(-15, 25)
    z += 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This generates random numbers, but they are not valid if I use my function valid_luhn(cc), right?